# parsing text file in python and creating dictionary of key value pair where values are in list format

Tags: python

How to process given data as below and store it using dictionary .

## Input:

```
Name Roll_number Subject Experiment_name Marks Result
Joy  23          Science Exp related to magnet 45 pass
Adi  12          Science Exp electronics       48 pass
kumar 18         Maths   prime numbers         49 pass
Piya 19          Maths   number roots          47 pass
Ron 28           Maths   decimal numbers       12 fail
```

## Output should be:

after parsing above Information and storing in dictionary where key is subject(unique) and values corresponding to subject is list of pass Student name

I have tcl working code as below , i wanted to convert it to python using same logic .

[parsing text file in tcl and creating dictionary of key value pair where values are in list format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761653/parsing-text-file-in-tcl-and-creating-dictionary-of-key-value-pair-where-values)

```
            set studentInfo [dict create]; # Creating empty dictionary
            set fp [open input.txt r]
            set line_no 0
            while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} {
            incr line_no
            # Skipping line number 1 alone, as it has the column headers
            # You can alter this logic, if you want to 
            if {$line_no==1} {
            continue
            }
            if {[regexp {(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*\s(\S+)} $line match name subject result]} {
            if {$result eq "pass"} {
            # Appending the student's name with key value as 'subject'
            dict lappend studentInfo $subject $name
            }
            }
            }
            close $fp
            puts [dict get $studentInfo]
```

i am stuck while processing the line data using python RE . Exactly i am unable to convert below code from tcl to python

```
            if {[regexp {(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*\s(\S+)} $line match name subject result]} {
            if {$result eq "pass"} {
            # Appending the student's name with key value as 'subject'
            dict lappend studentInfo $subject $name
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this will do what you want.

```py
import re

studentInfo = {} # create empty dict to fill
pattern = re.compile(r"(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*\s(\S+)") # compile patten to use

line = "Joy 23 Science Exp related to magnet 45 pass" # this is just for example

# repeat this for each line
match = pattern.match(line) # get match
name = match.group(1) # extract name
subject = match.group(2) # extract subject
result = match.group(3) # extract result
if result == "pass":
    studentInfo[subject] = name # add to dict
```